# Execute sh script using alias

Tags: command-line, alias, sh

I've written a script to run intellij idea using an alias and put it in a `.bashrc` file.

```sh
function idea {
     sh /opt/idea-IU-135.909/bin/idea.sh
}
```

I am trying to run it through terminal and get the following message

```
rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your script you call `rm`. If you delete folder try with `rm -rf`.

Comment: what is your alias and how are you running it? I guess there should be some special character in the name?

Comment: Are you sure it's an `sh` script and not a `bash` script?

Comment: @user3127896 it would be really helpful if you could copy the statement which is breaking in here.
+ Why arent you storing a real alias instead of a function? `alias idea="sh /path/to/idea.sh"`

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is true,in your script, you may be trying to delete a folder or file whose name contains some special character. e.g., `-myFile`

In that case you have to edit that line in your script. There are two options to use `rm` in this scenario.

1.Use the -- which signifies the end of option flags

```
rm -- -myFile
```

2.Use full path

```
rm /home/you/directory/-r
```

or, from the same directory:

```
rm ./-r
```